# Display value from Array in a dropdown and on the basis of selection filter key and call api?

Tags: angular, typescript, drop-down-menu

I am getting below Array from BE api call (which I can not change its not dummy Data)

> let arrayValues = [
> {
> "abc": "1"
> },
> {
> "ifg": "2"
> },
> {
> "cdk": "3"
> },
> ];

I want to display values like 1,2 and 3 in a dropdown. On the basis of value selected from dropdown I want to fetch its key and pass that key in another api call.

Suppose if user select value 3 then it should pass "cdk" in another api call and fetch values for another dropdown.
I tried below code to print the values in dropdown but i got object object

> 

```
     <mat-select *ngFor="let item of arrayValues | keyvalue" [value]="item.key">
                  <mat-option>{{item.value}}</mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>
```

I am not sure how to filter the key on the basis of value please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to restructure the object to be in JSON format.

The TypeScript should be like this

```
 arrayValues: any;
 selectedValue: string;
 newArray: any;

  ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.arrayValues = [{ "abc": "1" }, { "ifg": "2" }, { "cdk": "3" }];
    this.newArray = [];
    this.arrayValues.forEach(element => {
    this.newArray.push({ "key": Object.keys(element)[0], "value": Object.values(element)[0] })
});
  }

  onOptionsSelected(): void {
    console.log(this.selectedValue);
  }
```

The HTML should be like this

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Type" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (selectionChange)="onOptionsSelected()">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let type of newArray" [value]="type.key">
        {{ type.value}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

The value will be available in the variable selectedValue.

Comment: I can not restructured the array as I'm getting this format from BE. Can you tell me any way to access such array?

Comment: updated the code, used a new array to restructure the array to property format, then it is easy to work with.